# Switch Handles on electron app using selenium using Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, electron, automated-tests

Im trying to switch handles on my electron app using selenium. Currently im trying

```
 // Switch to new window opened
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
```

But this isnt causing a switch, ive tried to print the number of open windows using:

```
    System.out.println("Number of Handles: " + driver.getWindowHandles().toString());
```

but all im getting is Number of Handles: [CDwindow-9AAF3A83574341C2DF145765280C8BC1]

Comment: It has returned one handle because there could be only browser window opened. May be you are treating popup as window.

Comment: Possibly, how can i switch to the pop up then?

Comment: @FearghalQA : You need to post the html of the popup to check whether it an alert or a model.